# Suggested synonyms: [web-apps], [online-service], [web-service], probably [online]

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

[web-apps](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-apps) is asking for some synonyms. [online](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online) is suspicious, should it be a synonym of [web-apps](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-apps) too, or it is a misleadng meta tag, or neither of this?

Comment: Related discussion: [Tags for software that runs on a (web?) server](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/933/60)

Answer (score 4):

Tagging and synonyms are created when questions are asked in actual practice. There doesn't seem to currently be anymore questions tagged [online], so we don't generally create synonyms before there is an actual problem or use case for the tag.

Comment: I removed one: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/posts/908/revisions